# Getting 401 Error Response Status from GCM Server

Tags: android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying to send notifications to the devices installed my app. I've followed the instructions in [this Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), and successfully get the registration ID of my devices. However, I always get 401 response when I am sending my requests from my server.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is how I tested it:

```
api_key=MY_API_KEY
curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"MY_REGISTRATION_ID\"]}"
```

I've replaced MY_API_KEY with the project number on Cloud Console, and MY_REGISTRATION_ID with the result of the Android code `gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context); gcm.register(SENDER_ID);`

I know there're are a couple of people posting the same issue, and I've read all of them for hours. Sadly, their solutions didn't fix my bug. Please help, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the browser key instead of api key..

Comment: that's weird, where can I find the browser key?

Comment: In your google api console go into your project. Then on the left you find APIs & Auth > Registered Apps. There you should find the browser key

Comment: It seems that you're using "Web App" instead "Android" in the platform field on Cloud Console. Both server API key and browser API key work for me without 401 error. However, I haven't successfully received any notifications yet. Here's the response from GCM `{"multicast_id":462805484xxxxxxxxx,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1386725281760300%fde9a7xxxxxxxxx"}]}`

Comment: that seems like the message has been sent...For me now there is a problem in your app...

Comment: Wow, thanks!! I found one typo in my manifest, and now everything works pretty well!

Comment: @allemattio I am facing same issue, however, I'm unable to find "Browser key" in the new Google Developer Console because there is no Registered Apps option in APIs & Auth, can you tell me how to get it?

Comment: In the left of the page go to "APIs & AUTH" > "CREDENTIALS" then in the "Public Api Access" section click on "Create New Key" and Select browser key in the popup that appears